# GKE multi regional

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-kubernetes-engine

Application (pod) presently running in GLB<->GKE Europe (say Netherlands). I got requirement to scale the  application to serve customer in US and ASIA (say SFO & Japan).

I have noticed kubemci in beta.

Please help to clarify whether whether GKE need to duplicate in US & Asia or Europe is sufficient.

Please share some best practice/recommendation for this scenario.

Answer (score 1):

General approach is to create GKE clusters with identical configuration in regions. Whether you need a regional replica of the application or not, basically depends on the number of users in the region and response time limits.

A possible implementation you could follow is described here: [How to deploy geographically distributed services on Kubernetes Engine with kubemci](https://cloud.google.com/blog/products/gcp/how-to-deploy-geographically-distributed-services-on-kubernetes-engine-with-kubemci)

Then multiple clusters could be load balanced with the multi-cluster Ingress ([kubemci](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/how-to/multi-cluster-ingress))

As you've noticed, `kubemci` is in beta at this time and has limited support. Hence it is unlikely it's is applicable for production workloads; rather for the tryout.

Comment: Do you have any feedback on use GCP traffic detector for multi region?

Comment: GKE multi-cluster Services (MCS) available.

Reference link:
[1] https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/how-to/multi-cluster-services
[2] https://cloud.google.com/blog/products/containers-kubernetes/introducing-gke-multi-cluster-services

Answer (score 0):

I might be few weeks too late but this might be still relevant for someone.

> Caution: The kubemci tool is a temporary solution intended to help
>   users begin using multi-cluster Ingress. This tool will be replaced by
>   an implementation using kubectl that delivers a more Kubernetes-native
>   experience. Once the kubectl implementation is available, you will
>   need to manually migrate any apps that use kubemci.

I don't know your architecture but if applicable use [container native load balancing](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/how-to/container-native-load-balancing) with a [global load balancer](https://cloud.google.com/load-balancing/docs/https/).

Simple container native load balancer setup where you can do everything with Kubernetes resources doesn't give you global load balancing. You would need to use [standalone network endpoint groups](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/how-to/standalone-neg)(NEG). Create load balancer manually (or with whatever tooling you use), create [backend service](https://cloud.google.com/load-balancing/docs/backend-service) that includes NEGs for the same service in different clusters and add backend service to the load balancer. You will get the benefits of the [premium network tier](https://cloud.google.com/network-tiers/docs/overview) (lower latency for clients globally) and traffic spillover if the service is overloaded or down in one of the regions.